# Put two or more observations in one variable

Tags: r, string, sum, duplicates, repeat

I have a code which shows few number that represent the same string variable. there are  "1", "01" and "1", but they're all the same thing. How can I add these three string in one variable "1" without lose observations? here's an example:

```
  0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     .     0    00    01    02    03    04 
8011 18244  9289 32271 14412 14866 25329  3972  7086 44114   178   834     7    17    11    29    8
```

Comment: You need to give us the output of `dput` on that R object. I suspect it is a named numeric vector but we need to see the unambiguous structure and only `dput` will deliver that.

Comment: Where is the requested edit that puts in the dput output?????

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: So I get answers. Here's the code to identify the problem
unique(tb_2015_2020$situa_ence)

so I got this on the console: unique(tb_2015_2020$situa_ence)
 [1] "1"  ""   "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "7"  "10" "8"  "9"  " 2" " 5" " 4" " 8" " 1" " 3" " 9" " 7" "01" "02" "03" "04"[23] "05" "07" "08" "."

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think you might be working with:

```
inp2 <-  c(`0` = 8011, `1` = 18244, `2` = 9289, `3` = 32271, `4` = 14412, 
`5` = 14866, `6` = 25329, `7` = 3972, `8` = 7086, `9` = 44114, 
. = 178, `0` = 834, `00` = 7, `01` = 17, `02` = 11, `03` = 29, 
`04` = 8)
```

As I understand the request you want to group those second row numeric values on the basis of the numeric values of the first row. (You are not telling us what you want us to do with the items whose headings are periods.) I might assign those non-numeric names to 999 before the grouping operation:

```
 inp3 <- inp2
 names(inp3)[is.na(as.numeric(names(inp3)))] <- 999
#Warning message:
#In names(inp3)[is.na(as.numeric(names(inp3)))] <- 999 :
#  NAs introduced by coercion

 inp3
 #   0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9   999     0    00    01    02    03    04 
 #8011 18244  9289 32271 14412 14866 25329  3972  7086 44114   178   834     7    17    11    29     8
```

Then you can split on the "numericized" names:

```
split(inp3, as.numeric( names(inp3)))
# ---- result ----
$`0`
   0    0   00 
8011  834    7 

$`1`
    1    01 
18244    17 

$`2`
   2   02 
9289   11 

$`3`
    3    03 
32271    29 

$`4`
    4    04 
14412     8 

$`5`
    5 
14866 

$`6`
    6 
25329 

$`7`
   7 
3972 

$`8`
   8 
7086 

$`9`
    9 
44114 

$`999`
999 
178
```

if you want to get the sums within thos categories just use sapply on that list:

```
sapply( split(inp3, as.numeric( names(inp3))) , sum)
# --------------------------
    0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9   999 
 8852 18261  9300 32300 14420 14866 25329  3972  7086 44114   178
```

Comment: Lets take this example: 0 and 00 in the code means the same thing: "1-4 years of study". But before I give them a label, I have to sum the values related to 0 and 00 because they're the same categorie. The same thing happens with number "1 " and "01" and others... are the same categorie, but data.frame shows them separately. Is it better to understand now? Thank you very much

Comment: So you just want the sums within the categories I defined? (Why didn't you say you wnated to aggregate the values?)

Comment: Thank you IRTFM. Unfortunately the first code did not work. I put the following code and the message was " Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name" and "Error: unexpected ',' in " `5` = 14866,"
the code was:
escolaridade1 <-  c(0 = 8011, 1 = 18244, 2 = 9289, 3 = 32271, 4 = 14412, 
           5 = 14866, 6 = 25329, 7 = 3972, 8 = 7086, 9 = 44114, 
           . = 178, 0 = 834, 00 = 7, 01 = 17, 02 = 11, 03 = 29, 
           04 = 8, 05= 6, 06 = 10, 08= 1, 09= 24, 1= 3139, 10= 3565, 3= 11269, 
           4= 1, 5= 14111, 6= 2, 7= 3465, 8= 1778, 9= 11196 )
even with ´ it hasnt work

Comment: You are probably missing a quote or a backtick. When they are used for vector item names then need to be matched. Unfortunately your comment is probably not displaying correctly. You need to learn to [edit] your question body when posting code, rather than using comments which are very limited in how they display code.

Answer (score 0):

so I got it. my code to identify the problem was that one:

unique(tb_2015_2020$situa_ence)
[1] "1"  ""   "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "7"  "10" "8"  "9"  " 2" " 5" " 4" " 8" " 1" " 3" " 9" " 7" "01" "02" "03" "04"
[23] "05" "07" "08" "."

So, after see the characteristcs of each categorie I used the "mutate" fuction on dyplyr to aggregate the numbers:

tb_2015_2020<-tb_2015_2020%>%
mutate(desfecho1 =case_when((situa_ence=="1" )|(situa_ence==" 1")|(situa_ence=="01")~"g1.cura",
(situa_ence=="2")|(situa_ence==" 2")|(situa_ence=="02")~"g2.abandono",
(situa_ence=="3")|(situa_ence==" 3")|(situa_ence=="03")~"g3.óbito_TB",
(situa_ence=="4")|(situa_ence==" 4")|(situa_ence=="04")~"g4.óbito_outra_causa",
(situa_ence=="5")|(situa_ence==" 5")|(situa_ence=="05")~"g5.transferencia",
(situa_ence=="7")|(situa_ence==" 7")|(situa_ence=="07")~"g7.TB_DR",
(situa_ence=="8")|(situa_ence==" 8")|(situa_ence=="08")~"g8.Mudanca_esquema",
(situa_ence=="9")|(situa_ence=="9")~"g9.falencia",
(situa_ence=="10")~"g10.abandono_pri"))

now I have the categories correctly. Thanks everyone, Im new over here.